# POST request --> net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I'm writing a code using React.js on the client side and Express.js on the server side. When using the POST method to send the data from client to server and save it in a json file, I get this error:

[screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9q6np.png)

That's the client side code:

```
import { useState, useRef } from "react";

import NavBar from "./NavBar";

const AddMovie = () => {
  const [movieData, setMovieData] = useState({});
  const clearFormInput = useRef(null);

  const formDataHandler = (e) => {
    setMovieData({
      ...movieData,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  const submitDataHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    fetch("http://localhost:3001/add", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(movieData),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => console.log(data))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));

    clearFormInput.current.reset();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <NavBar />
      <form
        onSubmit={submitDataHandler}
        ref={clearFormInput}
        className="m-auto p-5 w-[30rem] bg-blue-400 relative top-60 transform -translate-y-1/2"
      >
        <div className="flex flex-col">
          <label htmlFor="title">Movie Title</label>
          <input
            onChange={formDataHandler}
            type="text"
            name="title"
            id="title"
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col">
          <label htmlFor="whereToWatch">Where do we find it?</label>
          <input
            onChange={formDataHandler}
            type="text"
            name="whereToWatch"
            id="whereToWatch"
            placeholder="e.g. NetFlix"
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col">
          <label htmlFor="description">Tell us about the movie</label>
          <textarea
            onChange={formDataHandler}
            name="description"
            id="description"
            type="text"
            required
          />
        </div>
        <button className="my-4 p-3 bg-blue-950 text-white rounded-md">
          Share Movie
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddMovie;
```

That's the server side code:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const uuid = require("uuid");

const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

const app = express();

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:5174",
  })
);
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("server is running...");
});

app.post("/add", (req, res) => {
  const movieData = req.body;

  console.log(movieData)
  movieData.id = uuid.v4();

  const filePath = path.join(__dirname, "data", "movies.json");

  const fileData = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
  const existingMovies = JSON.parse(fileData);
  existingMovies.push(movieData);

  fs.writeFileSync(filePath, JSON.stringify(existingMovies));
});

app.listen(3001);
```

I'm trying to save the data in the file movie.json, which it seems to be working but I'm still getting that error on the console.
I really appreciate the help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to await the fetch call

```
 async function submitDataHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    await fetch("http://localhost:3001/add", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(movieData),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => console.log(data))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));

    clearFormInput.current.reset();
  };
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I'm still coming across the same error:                    
POST http://localhost:3001/add net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at submitDataHandler (AddMovie.jsx:19:11)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (react-dom.development.js:4164:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:31)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:25)

Comment: t executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:3)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9073:7)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:9086:5)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:9097:3)
    at react-dom.development.js:9288:12
o